# Power Query split a column of text according to a separate column containing a list of integers

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I'm trying to use Power Query (m) to split a column of text strings called textStringColumn.

The points where I would like to split the column are in another column called indexColumn.

They are both in a table called myTable.

My approach was as here:

```
#"output" = Table.SplitColumn(myTable, ColumnToSplit, 
Splitter.SplitTextByPositions(indexColumn), textStringColumn, "default" )
```

This resulted in an error:

```
Expression.Error: There is an unknown identifier. 
Did you use the [field] shorthand for a _[field] outside of an 'each' expression?
```

Subsequent attempts using

```
#"output" = Table.SplitColumn(myTable, ColumnToSplit, 
each Splitter.SplitTextByPositions(indexColumn), textStringColumn, "default" )
```

produced the same error.

Could you advise how I might correct my query?

Thanks and regards.

EDIT: test data
('pretending' the input data was comma delimited since I can't cut and paste the list column)

```
textStringColumn,indexColumn
abc 1234 and ghyyyu 432,"[3,19]"
453,"[0]"
hky 7332 4343,"[3,8]"
```

Comment: Please post your sample data as copiable text and your expected output.

Comment: Is this Excel or PBI?

Comment: @David Bacci 
It is in excel but will feed PowerBI downstream. - the list column is generated earlier so it's hard to post a copy and paste version since it displays in the query as list. viewing each row does display a list of integers as expected. - it will feed PowerBI. example table (using a comma delimited list for the list column and pretending we have a comma delimited file would give the table above in the edit.

Comment: Did the solution work? How are you deriving your indices to split on? Can they not be derived at runtime in PQ rather than pre-calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your data, your output will look like this:

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSkxKVjA0MjZRSMxLUUjPqKysLFUwMTZS0lGKNtYxtIxVitWJVjIxNQYJGEB4GdmVCubGxkZAdSbGEIUWQJlYAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [textStringColumn = _t, indexColumn = _t]),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,"[","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"indexColumn"}),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value","]","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"indexColumn"}),
    #"Parsed List" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value1",{{"indexColumn", each List.Transform( Text.Split(_,","), each Number.FromText (_) ) }}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Parsed List", "Custom", each Splitter.SplitTextByPositions(   [indexColumn] )([textStringColumn])),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "|"), type text}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv))
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

There is probably a more efficient way to do this so keen to see if horseyride or Ron have alternatives.

Comment: Honestly I dont even understand the question, nor why splitting the first row and getting output that omits "abc" would be the right solution     I would have thought it would be each List.Distinct(List.Combine({{0},List.Transform( Text.Split(_,","), each Number.FromText (_) )}))}}),

Comment: Yes, I agree. Ignoring the logic of the split positions, I still couldn't find a way to make this work in a single operation using Table.Split()  and pass the column-referenced list to the Splitter function. If you know how, I'd love to see how.

Comment: I won't be at my computer for a few days, but it seems to me you could use split by character transition using space and the set of digits for the before and after arguments.

Comment: Dave - This works great! The key line was the #"Added Custom". @Ron Rosenfeld I think your idea might work too - I'll have a crack once I've got the first draft done. 
I had shown only a simplified sub set of the code - didn't want to complicate things but judging from the comments, I failed.  Out of interest, I added an expandListColumn wrapper to put each of these in rows then removed any non numeric characters. I have a unique record ident column not included here so any subsequent counts can be done on unique values. Thanks all - really appreciate the excellent feedback/help.

Comment: @simon.watson.sjw Fooled around a bit and, to duplicate the splits you show with your List of split positions, all you need to do is 1. Transform the column so that if the first "word" is all digits, then pre-pend a space. 2. Split by transition from "space" to digit. 3. Delete the first column.